# How can I evenly distribute menu links in div

Tags: html, css, navigation

I want to evenly distribute menu links inside a div element. When I float li left I stll get spaces to the right. [jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JsWtk/)
The html I 'm working with is

```
<div id="header" class="nav"> 
<ul >
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Vision</li>
    <li>Clients</li>
    <li>Partners</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

While the css is

```
#header {
position: relative;
width: 60%;
height: 40px;
margin: 0px auto;
font-size: 25px;
margin-top: 20px;
padding-top: 15px;
border-radius: 5px; 
background-color: black  ;
}

.nav ul
{
list-style: none;
padding: 10px 10px 0px 1px;
margin:  0;
}

.nav ul li
{
list-style: none;
float: left;
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by this "When I float li left I stll get spaces to the right. " if you can explain please .

Answer (score 2):

One method would be `ul{ display: table; table-layout:fixed; } li{ display: table-cell }`.

Here's your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JsWtk/8/).

**Note**: IE issue, again. For Internet Explorer it will work starting version 8.

More about [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display) and [table-layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/table-layout) properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `width: 20%;text-align:center` on your `.nav ul li` selector.

This should  evenly distribute the lis, but you also have to remove the padding.

However, my solution works for exactly 5 items in your list (due to the `width: 20%`)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution then add yut own style :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul{
   list-style-type:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   overflow:hidden;
}
li{
   float:left;
}
a{
   display:block;
   width:60px;
   background-color:#dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `width: 20%` to your `li` but decrease it if you plan on applying padding.
If you want `20px` of padding on the left you should set the width to around `17%` or lower to your preference.

PS: Always remember the CSS Box Layout Rule: `result = target / offset`.

Answer (score 0):

You got left Spaces because you didi this :

```
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
```

Padding: . . . .20px mean

```
padding-left:20px;
```

This is how it should like if you decrease the padding left pixels
[Preview on Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JsWtk/11/)

Comment: actually it means `padding-left` :)

Answer (score 0):

missing link , Here's your [updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JsWtk/12/).

```
<div id="header" class="nav"> 
<ul >
    <li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
</ul>


</div> 



#header {
   position: relative;
   width: 90%;
   height: 40px;
   margin: 0px auto;
   font-size: 25px;
   margin-top: 20px;
   padding-top: 15px;
   border-radius: 5px; 
   background-color: black  ;
   color: white;
   }
.nav ul{
   list-style: none;
   margin:  0;
   display: table;
   table-layout: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   }

.nav ul li{
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0 10px;
   font-weight: normal;
   display:table-cell;
   text-align: center;
}

.nav li > a{
   display:block;
   color : white;   
   text-decoration : none;
}
```